# How to split this long sentence and interpret it?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

When reading *The Go Programming Language*, I come across the following sentence:

> With sufficient effort, a good change can be accommodated without compromising
>   what Fred Brooks called the ‘‘conceptual integrity’’ of the design but **a bad change cannot, and a pernicious change** trades simplicity for its shallow cousin, convenience.

I can't understand (...) ***but a bad change cannot, and a pernicious change*** (...)。 How  to split this long sentence to make it more understandable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can introduce three kinds of changes (to a program?)

1. Good change: **can** be accommodated without compromising 'conceptual integrity'
2. Bad change: **cannot** be accommodated without compromising 'conceptual integrity'
3. Pernicious change:  trades simplicity for its shallow cousin, convenience.

---

Simplified meaning:

1. If you make a good change, it does not hurt the whole system.
2. If you make a bad change, it hurts the system as a whole, no matter what adjustments you make afterwards.
3. If you make a pernicious change, it makes some things more convenient, but some other things become less simple.